# How to add layout view and set another Activity to that?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How I can add a layout xml in current view, inner in ScrollView (ex: using addview()) and set another Activity (not the current activity) to controller this new layout?

I created this code, but I don't know how to set a new activity to control that.

```
View alertaView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.alerta, null);
layout.addView(alertaView);
```

Comment: I think android architecture does not work like that. One activity should not acces UI elements showing in another activity's layout.

Comment: It's possible separate the class to control new layout, like extend the current activity?

Comment: maybe you are looking for a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) ?

Comment: exactly! Thanks for your help.